# Apache Camel return producer errors

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have a simple proxy configuration like the following:

```
from("netty-http://0.0.0.0:8080/xyz")
    .toD("netty-http:" + "https://abc/xyu")
    .process(this::processResponse);
```

But when abc service return 400 with readable errors, camel return own exception:

`org.apache.camel.component.netty.http.NettyHttpOperationFailedException: Netty HTTP operation failed invoking`

What can I do to simply return the error from producer service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the [throwExceptionOnFailure](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/netty-http-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_throwExceptionOnFailure) option to false. Http components in camel have this enabled on default, probably so that failures can easily be caught and handled like any other exceptions in camel.

When its enabled you can get the Exception and details about the exception through Exchange properties which in this chase you can probably cast to `NettyHttpOperationFailedException` to get more information about it.

```java
Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
```

Comment: thanks, now http status is transmitted correctly but body is still missing.

Comment: Have you tested abc service using something like curl or postman to see that it actually responds with a body? If `throwExceptionOnFailure` is set to false camel should assign whatever body and headers provided by the response to the message.

Comment: You can also try getting more information using `.to("log:response?showAll=true")` to make camel log current message body and headers to get more information about what is actually returned. (Be vary that this logs all headers including credentials that you may have set to camel headers)

Comment: Great, Can i set `throwExceptionOnFailure` to all routes in my config?

Comment: Might be possible if you manage to configure `netty-http` component somehow, but unfortunately the documentation is a bit sparse when it comes to advanced scenarios like configuring components outside route definitions. Might be easier to just use string to hold shared options or use method to construct the URI with correct settings.

Comment: throwExceptionOnFailure solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with jetty ([Apache-Camel / Camel-Jetty / Don't return exception-stack-trace in case of 401 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121502/apache-camel-camel-jetty-dont-return-exception-stack-trace-in-case-of-401-r))

In my case the options `bridgeEndpoint=true` and `throwExceptionOnFailure=false` solved the issue (except for http 401)

```
from("netty-http://0.0.0.0:8080/xyz")
    .toD("netty-http:" + "https://abc/xyu?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .process(this::processResponse);
```